# Authors in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I want to insert Names of authors in the toc (above the chapter title) [like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110218/add-author-before-chapter-title-in-toc):
[image]

but the suggested methode doesn't work in the scrreprt type of document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Blabla 1}
sdadasdas

\section{Blabla 1.1}
fd
\subsection{Blabla 1.1.1}
das
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting [Gonzalo Medina's earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110256/5001**) to work with the `screport` instead of the `memoir` class isn't too difficult. The main thing that needs to be changed is to load the `tocloft` package explicitly. (It's loaded for you by the `memoir` class.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} %% is this needed/correct?

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 


%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}

%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! To get it work however, I had to comment lines 607 and 608 in the file tocloft.sty, because otherwise I got an error:     line  607: Command \c@lofdepth already defined. \newcounter{lofdepth}

Comment: @Dmitri - You're welcome. What gave rise to the difficulty you report? Did you try to issue the instruction `\setcounter{lofdepth}{0}` or something similar?

Comment: I don't even know, there is no command could break lofdepth (imho). `\setcounter{lofdepth}{0}` doesn't helps.