# Author before chapter in TOC in scrbook class

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]How can I get the author to go first in the TOC (within the scrbook-class - I did find solutions that seem to work with other classes...), while not changing anything about the headings etc., which work fine? There is probably an easy solution, but I don't see it!
Thanks for your help!

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 10pt, headings=small, toc=index, listof, toc=flat]{scrbook}
\usepackage[papersize={17.0cm, 24cm},left=2.2cm, right=2.8cm, top=2.6cm, bottom=0.8cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}[BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold.otf , ItalicFont = texgyrepagella-italic.otf , BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf ]
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries\centering}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\rmfamily\scshape\small}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont}

\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\linespread{1.1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}\markright{#1}}% setting \markright to author

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\cohead{\small{\leftmark}}
\cehead{\small{\rightmark}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
    {\centering\vspace*{10pt}%
        \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
        \par\nobreak\vspace*{30pt}}
    \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
        {\mdseries\scshape\protect\normalsize#1}{}{}}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap{\centering Überlegungen zu allem Möglichen}
    \chapterauthor{Mirijam Mustermann}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \addchap{\centering Fiktion und Fakten}
    \chapterauthor{Eva Mustermann}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code seems needlessly convoluted in places. Why use  `\addchap` instead of simply `\chapter`, e.g.? Also, perhaps you can show us the result you're ultimately looking for?

Comment: The answer to why I use \addchap instead of \chapter is in scrguide p. 113. I don't know, how I would show you the result, because I am not getting the result I want: I would like the author to go before the title of the chapter in the TOC, which it doesn't, and I don't know why.

Comment: The answers to this question I have found so far, are all for the class memoir, while I use scrbook.

Comment: I still can't quite picture what exactly you're trying to achieve. Can you add a mock-up? Fake the TOC in Word if you have to, but please show us an image of your desired result.

Comment: I just added, how the TOC looks like right now. I would like the chapterauthor to go before the title of the chapter. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: At the same time I want the chapterauthor after the title during the book. Title and author should be centered. I realize that my solution is not great and my affect the TOC.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175942/authors-in-the-table-of-contents

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it is the same: the author is still after the title in the toc, while she/he is not printed any more after the title of each chapter in the book and it has disappeared from the headings on each page, for which usepackage scrlayer-scrpage worked fine......

Comment: Still looking for a solution....