# Author before title in ToC with repetitions

Tags: table-of-contents

Here is a method for putting the author name before the title of a chapter in the ToC. [Add author before chapter title in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110218/add-author-before-chapter-title-in-toc), I mean the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110256/80224.

This works perfectly fine. But suppose one author writes multiple chapters, and we would like the toc to look something like this :

*Kafka*
The Rejection...........7
The Judgement......77

*Maupassant*
Love..............15
Pierrot...........33

*Tolstoy*
Three questions....40.

That is, even if the works by a particular author are not in order, they are classed under the same Author in the ToC, with no repetitions of Author.

How should I modify the code given here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110256/80224?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen

%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 

% Page style
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{\small\chapterauthor}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\slshape\leftmark}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
  \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}

%%
% Dokumentenbeginn
%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents* 
\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Hartman von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please include the code you are interested in here. If that answer gets edited, this question becomes useless. I'm not sure you want a ToC at all. This looks more like an index to me.

Comment: As you already figured out: Adding the author name with `\addtocontents` is not difficult, grouping the chapters for the same author **is** a problem! Are you sticking to the code above?

Comment: No, I am not sticking to the code above. I would only like to have a toc which looks like the form I have shown.

Comment: @usr203050: Ok, I have some almost working version, but `memoir` is a little bit tricky ;-)

Comment: Please show me anything, may be I can adapt it somehow... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is somewhat a hack...

The ordered appearance of `\chapter` in a `ToC` is 'messy' considered for the request, so I stored the contentslines in a `Atoc`, `Btoc` etc. file, where each author get's his own file, however only with 26 authors. If more is to be done, `alphalph` package will help ;-)

The `\chapter` macro does no longer write an entry to the `ToC`, but this can changed rather easily back to the defaults.

In the end (well, at the beginning actually), the `\authortableofcontents` collects all the individual `Atoc` etc. files and shows them a row.

The vertical spacing is wrong, most likely.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 



\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % Subsection mit Zähler (1.1) versehen




%%
% Kolumnentitel
%%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{}  } % Stil der Kopfzeile zurücksetzen
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} } % Stil der Kopfzeile 

% Page style
\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage}{\small\chapterauthor}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\slshape\leftmark}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

%%
% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}


\usepackage{blindtext}


%%%%% My additions and changes
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\listgadd{\authortoclist}{}



\newtotcounter{authorcounter}

\newcounter{dummycounter}
\newcounter{realposition}
\newcommand{\grabitem}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{dummycounter}
  \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}{%
    \setcounter{realposition}{\number\value{dummycounter}}
    \listbreak
  }{%
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}



\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%    
  \xifinlistcs{#1}{authortoclist}{%  Does have been there already?
    \setcounter{dummycounter}{0}
    \forlistloop{\grabitem{#1}}{\authortoclist}
    \typeout{found at \number\value{realposition}}
  }{%
    \gdef\chapterauthor{#1}%  Nope, new author name. 
    \refstepcounter{authorcounter}%
    \setcounter{realposition}{\number\value{authorcounter}}
    \listgadd{\authortoclist}{#1}
    \addtocontents{\Alph{realposition}toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}
  }%
}


%%% Kicking the chapter to the toc entry
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{% 
    \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{\Alph{realposition}toc}{chapter}{%
    \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
}{}{}


\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand{\authortableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \forloop{dummycounter}{1}{\value{dummycounter} < \numexpr\totvalue{authorcounter}+1}{%
    \@starttoc{\@Alph\c@dummycounter toc}%
  }%
}

%%% End of my additions

\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents*

\authortableofcontents

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}

\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext


\authortoc{Hartmann von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter[Unter der Linden]{Unter der Linden an der Heide}

\section{Text}

\begin{quote}
Under der linden 

an der heide, 

dâ unser zweier bette was, 

dâ muget ir vinden 

schône beide 

gebrochen bluomen unde gras. 

Vor dem walde in einem tal, 

tandaradei, 

schône sanc diu nahtegal.
\end{quote}


\authortoc{Hartmann von Aue}
\chapter{Der arme Heinrich}
\section{Text}

\blindtext

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Daz sluezzelin}

du bist mîn ich bin dîn 

des solt dû gewis sîn 

dû bist beslozzen 

in mînem herzen

verlorn ist daz slüzzelîn

dû muost immer drinne sîn


\authortoc{Shakespeare}
\chapter{Hamlet}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** A better version

Changes compared to the 1st version:

- Added the `\authortocname` which means the heading name of the author toc content  --> change with `\renewcommand{\authortocname}{...}` so something more appropiate
- The `\sections` etc. can appear in the author toc now too
- The number of authors isn't any longer limited to 26, since each author defines a number and the ending is `.1toc`, `.2toc`, etc.
- It works with `hyperref` as long that package is loaded after all patching to `\chapter` etc. have been made.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 


\usepackage{blindtext}


%%%%% My additions and changes
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{authortoconly}
\togglefalse{authortoconly}   % Set \toggletrue{authortoconly} if the chapters etc. and sections should not appear in the toc as well

\makeatletter

\listcsgadd{authortoclist}{} % This holds a list of author names

\newcommand{\addauthortolist}[2][authortoclist]{%    % wrapper command to add names to the author list 
  \listcsgadd{#1}{#2}%   % 
}


% A command to generate the toc ending
\newcommand{\authortoc@@tocname}[1]{%
  \arabic{#1}toc%
}


\newtotcounter{authorcounter}


% Helper counters
\newcounter{authtoc@@dummycounter}
\newcounter{authtoc@@position}

% Get the position of an author in the list
\newcommand{\authtoc@@getauthornumber}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{authtoc@@dummycounter}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{#2}{%
    \setcounter{authtoc@@position}{\number\value{authtoc@@dummycounter}}
    \listbreak
  }{%
  }%
}


% From the original O.P. 
\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\addvspace{10pt}\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape#1\par\addvspace{-7pt}}}



\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%    
  \xifinlistcs{#1}{authortoclist}{%  Is the author already known?
    \setcounter{authtoc@@dummycounter}{0}%
    \forlistcsloop{\authtoc@@getauthornumber{#1}}{authortoclist}%  loop through the names
  }{% Nope, the author has not been specified so far
    \refstepcounter{authorcounter}%  
    \addauthortolist[authortoclist]{#1}%   Store the author name
    \setcounter{authtoc@@position}{\number\value{authorcounter}}% Set the toc file to the author number
    \addtocontents{\authortoc@@tocname{authtoc@@position}}{\authortoctext{#1}}% Add the author name to the relevant author toc file
  }%
}


%%% Enabling chapters making additional entries to other tocs
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{% 
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \nottoggle{authortoconly}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{% 
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  }{}%
  \addcontentsline{\authortoc@@tocname{authtoc@@position}}{chapter}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \nottoggle{authortoconly}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
  }{}%
  \addcontentsline{\authortoc@@tocname{authtoc@@position}}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{\typeout{Patched @sect}}{}


\newcommand{\authortocname}{Autoreninhaltsverzeichnis}


% This is the standard latex kernel \@starttoc, it's not necessary if `book.cls` is used, but for `memoir.cls` etc. 
\def\latex@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
  \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}



\newcommand{\authortableofcontents}{%
  \chapter*{\authortocname
    \@mkboth{%
      \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \setcounter{authtoc@@dummycounter}{0}%
  \loop
  \ifnum\value{authtoc@@dummycounter} < \numexpr\totvalue{authorcounter}
  \stepcounter{authtoc@@dummycounter}%
  \latex@starttoc{\authortoc@@tocname{authtoc@@dummycounter}}%
  \repeat%
}
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


%%% End of my additions


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\authortableofcontents

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}

\chapter{Ich sass uf eynem Steine?}
\section{Und dachte Bein mit Beine}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext


\authortoc{Hartmann von Aue}
\chapter[Was auch immer]{So gebt nur mehr und immer mehr}
\section{Moralische Quellen der Irrationalitat}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter[Unter der Linden]{Unter der Linden an der Heide}

\section{Text}

\begin{quote}
Under der linden 

an der heide, 

dâ unser zweier bette was, 

dâ muget ir vinden 

schône beide 

gebrochen bluomen unde gras. 

Vor dem walde in einem tal, 

tandaradei, 

schône sanc diu nahtegal.
\end{quote}


\authortoc{Hartmann von Aue}
\chapter{Der arme Heinrich}
\section{Text}

\blindtext

\authortoc{Walter von der Vogelweide}
\chapter{Daz sluezzelin}

du bist mîn ich bin dîn 

des solt dû gewis sîn 

dû bist beslozzen 

in mînem herzen

verlorn ist daz slüzzelîn

dû muost immer drinne sîn


\authortoc{Shakespeare}
\chapter{Hamlet}

\section{The meaning of Brontosaurs to Shakespeare}
\subsection{Miss Ann Elk}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will add a better version without spurious spaces etc. ;-)

Comment: This works for the moment in any case. Thank you!

Comment: The new version is interesting and better. However, the first is also excellent. Thank you.

Comment: @usr203050: You made me thinking about a new package for such additions to the toc.

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer, I think many people will be interested in such flexible toc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that should be workable. It assumes you have a relatively small list of authors, since their names are hard-coded into the author list commands and files.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\authortoc}[2]{
  \chapter{#2}
  \addcontentsline{#1}{chapter}{\numberline{#2}}\par%
}

\newcommand{\listkafkaname}{Kafka}
\newlistof{listofkafka}{kafka}{\listkafkaname}
\newcommand{\listmaupassantname}{Maupassant}
\newlistof{listofmaupassant}{maupassant}{\listmaupassantname}
\newcommand{\listtolstoyname}{Tolstoy}
\newlistof{listoftolstoy}{tolstoy}{\listtolstoyname}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\listofkafka*
\listofmaupassant*
\listoftolstoy*

\authortoc{kafka}{The Rejection}

\authortoc{maupassant}{Love}

\authortoc{maupassant}{Pierrot}

\authortoc{tolstoy}{Three Questions}

\authortoc{kafka}{The Judgment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is useful. Also, deleting the 
    \tableofcontents*
 works as well, and it gives almost what I want.