# How to place the author name before the chapter title

Tags: chapters

I need to place the individual chapter author name above the chapter title.

`\@afterheading` is used to place the author name after chapter title. I will try to use `\@beforeheading%` alternatively. But the macro is not running. Please advice how to place the author name before the chapter title both `toc` and chapter opening page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\chapterauthor*[1]{\printchapterauthor{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\parindent0pt\vspace*{-25pt}%
  \linespread{1.1}\large\scshape#1%
  \par\nobreak\vspace*{35pt}}
  \@afterheading%
}
\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{1st chapter}
\chapterauthor{K.DINESH KUMAR}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Required Output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you  take a look at the documentation of `titlesec`.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257096/author-before-title-in-toc-with-repetitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest defining a new command for such headings taking two arguments: the title and the author.  The macro should essentially just call `\chapter` with the author followed by the title, but wrapped into appropriate formatting commands to suit your needs.  For example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\chapterauthor[1]{\authortoc{#1}\printchapterauthor{#1}}

\newcommand{\printchapterauthor}[1]{%
  {\textnormal{\large\scshape#1}\\[2ex]}}

\newcommand{\authortoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-10pt}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}%
    {\hskip1.3em\mdseries\scshape\protect\scriptsize#1}{}{}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip5pt}%
}

\newcommand{\chapterwithauthor}[2]{\chapter[#1]{\printchapterauthor{#2}#1}\authortoc{#2}\markboth{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapterwithauthor{1st chapter}{K.~DINESH KUMAR}
\lipsum[1-10]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is working good.

Comment: how i can get rid of chapter 1 from this. i tried modifying {\chapter[#1] to {\chapter*[#1] but it is not working.