# Align TOC entries; title left and author right

Tags: table-of-contents, align

I am preparing a group report in LaTeX, assembling many parts written by different authors.

I'd like to write the authors name right aligned into the `\subsection{}` entry in the TOC, right next to the page numbers. Therefore i've tried to `\hfill` the line. Unfortunately this is resulting in a "messy" order (picture below), it seems like the author names are center aligned in the remaining space?

The minimal reproducible code snippet i've tried:

```latex
\subsection{TITLE \hfill \textit{AUTHOR}} \par
```

Does anybody know how to handle that? Otherwise i have to use `\subsection[]{}` to write the authors name right next to the title.

[image: Example]

Comment: Would this be a suitable compromise: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110218/add-author-before-chapter-title-in-toc?rq=1

Comment: Nice idea although i can't use this technique for my document because it needs too much space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
% tocauthorprob.tex SE 545459
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{} % no leader between subsection title and page number

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{TITLE \hfill \textit{AUTHOR}}
\end{document}
```

Read the documentation, `texdoc tocloft` for details about the package.